# Can't submit forms with Norwegian characters

Tags: php, mysql

When i'm trying to submit articles and forms with Norwegian characters to MySQL the results returns blank. I can't simply use Æ, Ø or Å. Any ideas how I can fix this? I'll handle almost every forms simply with `$_POST[]`. ISO is set in HTML.

I don't know if it's important, but the server is built on Xampp.

Please let me know if you need something more particular information.

Appreciate any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Check all character sets in html, php and mysql (and in server config). Possible there is utf-8/utf8 (or smth else) somewhere or in defaults.

Or use utf-8/utf8 anywhere better.